# Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar':

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have probem with spring application. I trying connect jwt with my rest api app. When I try run app, I get error and I don't know where I make mistake. Thanks for all answers.

Console log

```
2020-10-02 18:09:10.938  WARN 2052 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-10-02 18:09:10.955  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2020-10-02 18:09:11.027  WARN 2052 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@3eb3232b of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2020-10-02 18:09:11.027  INFO 2052 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-02 18:09:11.051  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-10-02 18:09:11.119  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-10-02 18:09:11.223  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-10-02 18:09:11.235  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
2020-10-02 18:09:11.722  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-10-02 18:09:11.730  INFO 2052 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-10-02 18:09:11.734  INFO 2052 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-02 18:09:11.735  INFO 2052 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-02 18:09:11.744  INFO 2052 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2020-10-02 18:09:11.746  INFO 2052 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-10-02 18:09:11.759  INFO 2052 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-02 18:09:11.772 ERROR 2052 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@3eb3232b of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.joledzki.baserest.BaserestApplication.main(BaserestApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@3eb3232b of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@3eb3232b of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter$CompositeObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:122) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:81) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:87) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(DaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:32) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:37) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:383) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:329) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:272) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:202) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.joledzki.baserest.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fcfee8a9.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@3eb3232b': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:406) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:67) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:100) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted

application.properties

    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baserest
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.application.admin.enabled=true
    spring.application.admin.jmx-name=org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=BaserestApplication
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter;

    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    public SecurityConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

AuthenticationFilter.java

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),User.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not read request " + e);
        }
    }

    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication){
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((User)authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 864_000_000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "aaa".getBytes())
                .compact();
        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
    }
}
```

AuthorizationFilter.java

```
public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer")){
            chain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthentication(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        chain.doFilter(request,response);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request){
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(token != null){
            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("aaa".getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer ",""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            if(user != null){
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            else return null;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I trying to fix it for 2 hours, but I still don't know where I'm making a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:100) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

You need to set **UserDetailsService** in your class **SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.**

Do one thing, create a class which implements UserDetailsService and then use UserServiceImpl in that.

Ultimately you need UserDetailsService in the SecurityConfig class.